# How to make my program read edge of screen so that can window snapping

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have a program of WPF using .Net C#.

please help me how to make my program can read edge of screen so that can window snapping.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SystemParameters.WorkArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.workarea.aspx) rectangle Or
 [SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenwidth) and [SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenheight) for screen size.

Comment: Not a good idea because it will not take into account the taskbar or other docked windows. If anything, SystemParameters.WorkArea gives the usable "desktop" region on the primary monitor. But a proper solution should taken into account multiple monitors. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162729.aspx